# Spark read from parquet hive table having timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet table in Hive which has date & timestamp fields. I would now like to read this table from over spark, but it fails with the parquet timestamp compatibility error.

The hive version is 1.2.1 & Spark version is 1.6.1

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parquet does not support timestamp. See HIVE-6384
>   App 
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ArrayWritableObjectInspector.getObjectInspector(ArrayWritableObjectInspector.java:98)
>   App 
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ArrayWritableObjectInspector.(ArrayWritableObjectInspector.java:60)

I tried reading from over Hive, it works perfectly fine. However fails when read from over Spark. Here is the query that am trying to run.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._ 
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("select * from hivetablename limit 10")
```

The hive table looks like below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hivetablename (col1 string, date_time timestamp, somedate date) PARTITIONED BY (load_date date) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'  
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3n://path'
```

Any suggestions or workarounds ?

Comment: what version of hive and spark you are using ? can you paste the code which is giving this error

Comment: set  spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet confuguration to false. When set to false, Spark SQL will use the Hive SerDe for parquet tables instead of the built in support. hopefully this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Configuration of Parquet can be done using the setConf method on SQLContext or by running SET key=value commands using SQL.

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu I tried adding it with the command line parameter  "--conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false". It failed with the same error message.

Comment: it looks like version compatibility issues , you may have to try with latest version of the hive once .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick check, please see which Hive version your Spark is referring to? Make sure it is not referring to older Hive version (<= Hive 0.13).

Comment: That's correct, the hive metastore it internally refers to is 0.13.1. I tried changing it to a newer version (0.14.0, 1.2.1) however, it fails with a different error now. -- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getTimeVar(org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: I tried setting up a test cluster with latest version of hive with Spark 1.6 & it worked fine. The issue seems completely related to older versions of hive metastore.

Comment: Hi Akarsh, Which version of hive did you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check for the Spark Version and its hive dependency version (is it compatible)

If both spark version and hive version are compatible and still getting the error then check with the following:
Add the following in your spark configuration
a) spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 1.2.1
b) spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars builtin

If you are using databricks cluster you can add these to the cluster configuration:
`Configuration`->`Advanced Options`->`Spark`-> `Spark Conf`

the support was added for `1.2.x` version

Comment: Hi Ravindra, wellcome to SO. Maybe the user has to upgrade Hive dependency to match perfectly with spark version.

Comment: Hi Neo, it could be the other way also. User may need to upgrade spark version.